# Android communicate Activity with Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, communication

I don't know what's going on, but I am getting an exception and the app freezes.

**Main activity:**

```
public class MainAcitivty extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    // ...

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener
    {
        public void onItemSelected(int resourceId);
    }

    OnItemSelectedListener mCallback;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.my_imageView)
        {
            mCallback.onItemSelected(R.id.my_imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment implements MainAcitivty.OnItemSelectedListener
{
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(int resourceId)
   {
       Log.i("INFO", "Selected: " + resourceId);
   }
}
```

If I click the selected button, the app freezes and the following Exception is throw:

> E/AndroidRuntime(21649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> com.example.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(21649):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method)

Comment: mCallback is not initiated

Answer (score 4):

in `MyActivity` add method

```
    public void addListener(MainAcitivty.OnItemSelectedListener listener){
        mCallback = listener;
    }
```

and invoke this method in `onViewCreated()` of `MyFragment`. 
`((MyActivity) getActivity).addListener(this);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which line 53 is but your `mCallback` is probably null.  Check that before dereferencing it.